# Helpdesk, community, knowledgebase, documentation

Tags: documentation-generator, crm, saas, help-desk

We're building a SaaS app. I'd like use another SaaS to handle the customer service parts of the app. Specifically, I'm looking for:

1. Single sign-on. When the customer signs into our app, they should be able to click a "Help" link and already be signed into the other service.
2. Email-based support.
3. A good community. Users should be able to post questions and have other users answer them. Ideally, we'd have something Stack Overflow-like.
4. Documentation. I want a place to write a user guide. It needs to accessible only behind the sign in. It should be searchable.
5. Knowledge base. It would be nice to have a place to write how-to articles. Could just be part of the documentation system.

Answer (score 2):

Give our app a try - [Jitbit Helpdesk](https://www.jitbit.com/helpdesk/).

1. We support various SSO methods - from Google Login to custom SAML providers (Azure AD for example)
2. Email-based is our primary focus.
3. We have a feature called Ideas Forum (you can rename it in settings). It is basically a forum where users can talk to each other, ask questions and make suggestions.
4. You can put documentation in private Knowledge Base articles and categories. It will be searchable and not visible to anonymous users.
5. We do have a powerful and customizable KB.

Disclamer: I'm a co-founder of the company.

Comment: Welcome Max! In your answer, please disclose your exact affiliation with this product.  Thanks!

Comment: From what I've seen, it really is a very powerful (and easy) system... I'm glad I met it, I've been looking for something like this for a LONG time (I've tried almost 20 products and none convinced me). I really want to try it.